# Come up with Better Module Pattern for Node/ES6 Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling to come up with a pattern that will satisfy both my tests and ability for Travis to run my script.

I'll start off by saying that the way I have Travis running my script is that I specify the script to be run via node-babel command in my **travis.yml** as so:

```
script:
  - babel-node ./src/client/deploy/deploy-feature-branch.js
```

That means when babel-node runs this, I need a method to auto run in `deploy-feature-branch.js` which I have.  That's the line `let { failure, success, payload } = deployFeatureBranch()`.  That **forces** `deployFeatureBranch()` **to run** because it's set to a destructure command.

In there I also have an `options` object:

```
let options = {
  localBuildFolder: 'build',
  domain: 'ourdomain',
  branch: process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH
}
```

During a PR build, travis automatically sets the value for `process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH`. That's great!  However the way I've set up this module doesn't work so well for tests.  The problem I have is that **if I try to set options from my test, for some reason the options object isn't being set**.

I guess the problem I want to address is first and foremost, why options isn't being set when I try to set them from my test.  And then is there a better way to design this module overall.

**Test**

```
import {options, deployFeatureBranch } from '../../../client/deploy/deploy-feature-branch'

    it.only('creates a S3 test environment for a pull request', async () => {
      options.branch = 'feature-100'
      options.domain = 'ourdomain'
      options.localDeployFolder = 'build'

      const result = await deployFeatureBranch()
      expect(result.success).to.be.true
    })
})
```

When `deployFeatureBranch()` runs above in my test, the implementation of 
 tries to reference `options.branch` but it ends up being `undefined` even though I set it to be `'feature-100'`.  branch is defaulted to process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH but I want to be able to override that and set it from tests.

**deploy-feature-branch.js**

```
import * as deployApi from './deployApi'

let options = {
  localBuildFolder: 'build',
  domain: 'ourdomain',
  branch: process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH
}

const deployFeatureBranch = async (options) => {
    console.log(green(`Deploying feature branch: ${options.branch}`))
    let { failure, success, payload } = await deployApi.run(options)
    return { failure, success, payload }
}

let { failure, success, payload } = deployFeatureBranch(options)

export {
  options,
  deployFeatureBranch
}
```

I can't really think of a better way to structure this and also to resolve the setting options issue.  I'm also not limited to using Node Modules either, I would be fine with ES6 exports too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exporting `options` and modifying it, just pass in your new `options` object when calling the function in your test:

```
import {deployFeatureBranch } from '../../../client/deploy/deploy-feature-branch'

    it.only('creates a S3 test environment for a pull request', async () => {
      const options = {
        branch: 'feature-100',
        domain: 'ourdomain',
        localDeployFolder: 'build'
      };

      const result = await deployFeatureBranch(options)
      expect(result.success).to.be.true
    })
});
```

The reason it isn't working is because your `deployFeatureBranch()` function expects `options` to be passed in when you call it, which you aren't doing.

Also, exporting and changing an object, while it might work, is also really weird and should be avoided. Creating a new object (or cloning the exported object) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I know but I want to enforce a contract.  I want only certain fields to be allowed

Comment: and I thought I was passing options to it: `const deployFeatureBranch = async (options)`

Comment: `async (options) => {}` is only declaring a function that takes a parameter which you call `options` inside of that function. The line where you destructure is the one where you are actually calling the function and passing your options. Also, exporting and modifying the object isn't really enforcing a contract. You could easily say `option.crazyCookieMonsters` and it would work just fine. In reality though, there isn't a reason to explicitly disallow other parameters. It won't hurt anything in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: As for cloning, you shouldn't modify an export, because it can cause wonky things to happen. It's the only version of that export, and it'll get changed for everything that imports it. A much better solution if you need to modify that object is to clone it first, then modify the clone. It's just a good practice that avoids odd and difficult to track bugs.

Comment: If you really want to enforce a contract, instead of accepting options: `async (options) => {}`, destructure the parameters as they come in and build a fresh object with only those. Then anything extra will get thrown away: `async ({ a, b, c}) => { myFunc({ a, b, c}); }`

Comment: thanks much.  Did not think of using destructuring for a contract.  That gets me half way there, then just add flowtype to enforce typing.

Comment: and if I didn't call deployFeatureBranch with that line where I destructure out the results, then const deployFeatureBranch = async (options) would actually take in the options instead and I could call deployFeatureBranch(options) and it'd still work

Comment: I am going go the route of removing the export for options then, and then I won't need to create a new instance of it.

Comment: last question, I changed it to `const deploy = async (options) => {
    const { branch } = options ..rest of the code }`.  I'm thinking about adding a property on the fly for `process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH` which is set by Travis.  So I'm thinking right after that const line, to just do options.branch = process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH.  What do you think in terms of adding a default like this?

Comment: You could definitely do that. I usually set defaults as a fallback. Something like `options.branch = options.branch || process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH;`. If you explicitly give one, use the one passed. Otherwise, use a default.